# Proof that an infinite product of discrete spaces may not be discrete

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that an infinite product of discrete spaces may not be discrete.  I tried taking the simplest nontrivial discrete space, $X:=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology, and tried to find a sequence of $0$s and $1$s in $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ that can't be produced by taking intersections of preimages of open sets in the factor spaces under the projection maps, but couldn't come up with anything.

Is this a good approach, or is this actually too simple of an example?

How would you go about solving this problem?  I'd be interested in hearing the thought process behind the proof as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The product you describe is compact by Tychonoff's theorem, but the only compact discrete spaces are the finite ones.

The thought process behind this proof is strongly informed by the material in [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/boolean-rings-ultrafilters-and-stones-representation-theorem/). A product of finite discrete spaces is an example of a profinite set or [Stone space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras#Stone_spaces), and these behave in very particular ways.

Alternatively, the product you describe is [second-countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space), which an uncountable discrete space isn't.

Comment: To supplement, $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set. The homeomorphism is the obvious one: For example, the sequence $001101\dots$ of zeros and ones is identified with the unique point in the Cantor set that is on $[0,1/3]$, $[0,1/9]$, $[2/27,1/9]$, $[8/81,1/9]$, $[8/81,25/243]$, $[74/729,25/243],\dots$

Comment: @Qiaochu: This is much nicer than just finding a subset that's not open.  That's the sort of thing I need to work on coming up with.  Thanks.

Comment: @Alex: I should also mention that working through Munkres helps. IIRC there is a lot of emphasis on proving that spaces aren't homeomorphic by proving that one satisfies a topological property the other doesn't.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 18):

More elementarily: The open sets in $\prod_{\mathbb N}\{0,1\}$ are precisely the (possibly infinite) unions of cylinder sets. Because even a single cylinder set is infinite, so is every nonempty open set. In particular, a singleton cannot be open, so the space is not discrete.

Comment: Is the term "cylinder" a standard? I did graduate work in topology, and I've never seen it before in this sort of context.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Standard enough for someone to have written a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set) using it.

Comment: Yeah, I just mean, the person asking is probably working from a textbook that made certain definitions, and adding new terms which requires looking up on Wikipedia doesn't seem like a pedagogically sound plan

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Well, since I learn these things from Wikipedia, I don't know what are in people's textbooks. The wikipedia article gave me the impression that this was a standard term people use for talking about bases for infinite product topologies, so I used it.

Comment: @Thomas: I think that the term comes from measure theory. I don’t remember encountering it in the topological sense until fairly recently.

Comment: For what it's worth: the term was in fact new to me, and I ended up going to the Wikipedia article to learn what a cylinder set was.  An included definition would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example derived directly from this answer at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/240345/22019). Let $(0)$ be the constant sequence of $0$'s. For $i\in\omega$, let $Z_i$ be the set of all those sequences that have $0$ at the i-th cordinate. By the definition of the product topology, for every open set $V$ containing $(0)$ there can only be finitely many $Z_i$'s such that $V\subseteq Z_i$. But $\{(0)\}=\bigcap_{i\in\omega}Z_i$, so $\{(0)\}$ is not open.

Of course Henning's answer is more general, but this gives some additional insight at *what is going on in the product*.